# Modify placeholder - Jquery Sumoselect - Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, sumoselect.js

I'm using a plugin Jquery [SumoSelect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) Multi Select in my application and I'm wondering how to switch the placeholder a select intance is reloaded.

I load new options via AJAX in a "select" instance but the placeholder remains the same that has been set at the beginning.

HTML Select

```
<Select id = "c_ba" multiple = "multiple" disabled> </select>
```

INSTANCE

```
 $("#C_ba").SumoSelect ({
placeholder "Neighborhoods", //initial placeholder
okCancelInMulti: true,
selectAll: true
});
```

In another Select I recharge the select above:

```
$('#C_ci').Change(function (e) {
SelectValue var = $(this).val();

$ .ajax ({
type: 'GET'
url: 'rotinas.asp'
date: "action = carrega_bairros & cod_cidade = '+ SelectValue,
success: function (html) {

var str = html;
var arr = str.split ("###");
arraux var = new Array ();

var select = $("#c_ba"); //html select initial
var options = '';

select.css ({'display', 'none'});
select.empty ();

if (str! = '') {
for (var x = 0; x <arr.Length; x ++) {
arraux = arr [x] .Split ("...");
options + = "<option value = '" + arraux [0] + "'>" + arraux [1] + "</ option>";
}

select.append (options);
select [0] .sumo.enable (); // Enable the SUMO SELECT 
select [0] .sumo.reload (); // Reload With news options loads

// Here I would like to exchange the original placeholder "Neighborhoods" to the following placeholder (eg.): "Select the Neighborhoods"

} Else {
select [0] .sumo.disable ();
select [0] .sumo.reload ();
}
},

error: function (e) {
// Called When there is an error
console.log (e.Message);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of Sumoselect, maximum priority is given to native placeholder attribute in select tag. So you can change the placeholder attribute of the select tag (using jQuery attr() method) before reloading sumoselect.

```
select.append(options);
select.attr("placeholder","Select the Neighborhoods");
select[0].sumo.enable();
select[0].sumo.reload();
```